# The definition of char (*(*a)())[];

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, function-pointers

I'm having trouble understanding
`char (*(*a)())[]`

```
int main()
{    
    char (*(*a)())[]; // do not change this

    char *x="My endless\n";

    char *  func (){
        return(x);
    }

    a=func;
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile I get a warning as follows:
main.c:13:6: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

which refers to `a=func`

I know that `char (*(*a)())` means a pointer to a function which returns a char pointer but I don't know what the addition of `[]` does to it, i.e. `char (*(*a)())[];`

Comment: first you cannot define a function inside an other one, move *func* definition out of *main* and adapt its definition

Comment: https://cdecl.org/

Comment: @bruno: The C standard allows extensions such as defining functions inside functions, and GCC supports this.

Comment: @EricPostpischil creating a closure ? wow

Comment: @bruno: it's not a fully-featured closure because it doesn't enclose bound variables; they are only valid during their normal lifetime. See the [gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html): "If you try to call the nested function through its address after the containing function exits, all hell breaks loose."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
char (*(*a)())[];
```

is a declaration of a pointer to function that returns pointer to an array of incomplete type `char[]`.

Pay attention to that defining functions within another functions is not a standard C feature.

Here is a demonstrative program that at least compiles.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char ( *f() )[]
{
    static char s[][10] =
    {
        "Hello",
        "World"
    };

    return s;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char (*(*a)())[] = f;

    char ( *p )[] = a();

    puts( *p );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello
```

In this program using casting like

```
char ( *p )[10] = ( char ( * )[10] ) a();
```

you could get a pointer to a complete array type.

Answer (score 2):

To decipher complicated C declarations you can use the spiral rule, see http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html. There is also a tool for translating C declarations into plain English:

https://cdecl.org/

In general, it is better to divide a complicated declaration into parts and give them meaningful names, for example

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef char (*ArrayPointer)[];
typedef ArrayPointer (*Function)();

int main(void)
{
    char (*(*a)())[] = NULL;
    Function b;

    b = a;
    return 0;
}
```